# Windows 10 on Microsoft Surface acting up. Windows closing, right click not working

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-surface

Windows10 on MS Surface is acting really weird.

Symptoms:

- I open Putty. As soon as I click on the UI or type anything in there, it shuts down. this happens to various apps: they close as soon as I click on them.
- I try to right click on the desktop. Seemed like the menu popped up for 0.00001 second but disappears. Either that or no response at all.
- I click on Windows icon on the task bar. The start menu appears for about half a 0.1 second and disappears.

Temporary fix:

Disconnect Surface keyboard and reconnect it. Then things seem to be normal again and I can use the computer. But only temporarily. The problem comes back in an hour or so. Hard to predict the timing.

If I disconnect the Surface keyboard entirely, it seems fine too. So I connect a Logitech USB keyboard+mouse but after some time, the same symptoms come back. Windows key on the USB keyboard doesn't seem to work. Active windows close for no reason.

Anyone had these problems?

I tried updating drivers, removing all sorts of apps.... disabling Tablet mode...

Nothing really seems to have a permanent fix.

Comment: when the issues occur do you see anything in event viewer that could relate?